# Create post_save signal for foreign key fields

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a profile model which contains experience and education as foreign key fields.
When I access profile template, it throws.

[image]

I tried post_save,

```
def create_education(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(education=instance)

    post_save.connect(create_education, sender=CustomUser)
```

it throws this error,

[image]

How do I define a post_save signal so experience and education are created when I create a profile?

Note: I double checked the error is because foreign fields are empty i.e there is no error when I add experience and education fields in django admin.

**models.py**

```
class Work_Experience(models.Model):
    job_title       = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    company         = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    description     = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    exp_start_date  = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    exp_end_date    = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)


class Education(models.Model):
    degree      = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    school      = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    edu_start_date  = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    edu_end_date    = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

class Profile(models.Model):    
    experience    = models.ForeignKey(Work_Experience, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    education     = models.ForeignKey(Education, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProfileSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    job_title      = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=False)
    company        = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=False)
    description    = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=False)
    exp_start_date = forms.DateField(required=False)
    exp_end_date   = forms.DateField(required=False)

    degree         = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=False)
    school         = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=False)
    edu_start_date = forms.DateField(required=False, input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
    edu_end_date   = forms.DateField(required=False, input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)

        super(ProfileSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['job_title'].initial = self.instance.experience.job_title
        self.fields['company'].initial = self.instance.experience.company
        self.fields['description'].initial = self.instance.experience.description
        self.fields['exp_start_date'].initial = self.instance.experience.exp_start_date
        self.fields['exp_end_date'].initial = self.instance.experience.exp_end_date

        self.fields['degree'].initial = self.instance.education.degree
        self.fields['school'].initial = self.instance.education.school
        self.fields['edu_start_date'].initial = self.instance.education.edu_start_date
        self.fields['edu_end_date'].initial = self.instance.education.edu_end_date

    def save(self, commit=True):
        model = super(ProfileSettingsForm, self).save(commit=False)
        jt = self.cleaned_data['job_title']
        co = self.cleaned_data['company']
        desc = self.cleaned_data['description']
        esd = self.cleaned_data['exp_start_date']
        eed = self.cleaned_data['exp_end_date']

        degree = self.cleaned_data['degree']
        school = self.cleaned_data['school']
        edusd = self.cleaned_data['edu_start_date']
        edued = self.cleaned_data['edu_end_date']


        if model.experience:
            model.experience.job_title = jt
            model.experience.company = co
            model.experience.description = desc
            model.experience.exp_start_date = esd
            model.experience.exp_end_date = eed
            model.experience.save()
        else:
            model.experience = Work_Experience.objects.create(job_title=jt,
                                                              company=co,
                                                              description=desc,
                                                              exp_start_date=esd,
                                                              exp_end_date=eed)

        if model.education:
            model.education.degree = degree
            model.education.school = school
            model.education.edu_start_date = edusd
            model.education.edu_end_date = edued
            model.education.save()
        else:
            model.education = Education.objects.create(degree=degree,
                                                       school=school,
                                                       edu_start_date=edusd,
                                                       edu_end_date=edued)
        if commit:
            model.save()

        return model
```

**Views.py**

```
class ProfileSettingsView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = ProfileSettingsForm
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk'
    context_object_name = 'object'
    template_name = 'profile_settings.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
          return reverse_lazy('users:profile_settings', args = (self.object.id,))
```

**UPDATE**

If I remove the init() method in form, the error resolves. But I don't get the values from database in the form fields once I save it.
How can I rewrite init() method?

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)

        super(ProfileSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['job_title'].initial = self.instance.experience.job_title
        self.fields['company'].initial = self.instance.experience.company
        self.fields['description'].initial = self.instance.experience.description
        self.fields['exp_start_date'].initial = self.instance.experience.exp_start_date
        self.fields['exp_end_date'].initial = self.instance.experience.exp_end_date

        self.fields['degree'].initial = self.instance.education.degree
        self.fields['school'].initial = self.instance.education.school
        self.fields['edu_start_date'].initial = self.instance.education.edu_start_date
        self.fields['edu_end_date'].initial = self.instance.education.edu_end_date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why the error?

In the line:

```
self.fields['job_title'].initial = self.instance.experience.job_title
```

you're dealing with a `Profile` instance that does not have a related `experience`.

### How do I define a post_save signal so experience and education are created when I create a profile?

If you want every time you create a `Profile` it gets populated with am `experience` and `education` you should have a signal like:

```
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        experience = Work_Experience.objects.create(profile=instance)
        education = Education.objects.create(profile=instance)

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=Profile)
```

### Why the `post_save` signal is not triggered when calling the `save()` of the form?

```
model = super(ProfileSettingsForm, self).save(commit=False)
```

According the docs:

> This save() method accepts an optional commit keyword argument, which accepts either True or False. **If you call save() with commit=False, then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the database**. In this case, it’s up to you to call save() on the resulting model instance. This is useful if you want to do custom processing on the object before saving it, or if you want to use one of the specialized model saving options. commit is True by default.

So by the time you do:

```
model.experience.job_title = jt
```

your `post_save` signal hasn't been triggered and therefore `model.experience` remains `None` hence the error:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute job_title.

Comment: I removed commit=False as you suggested, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Yes, that was a bug present but not the cause of your, primary question, I've adited the answer. The thing is that your are trying to access experience attribute for a newly created profile that not have a experience instance related, see the answer to see how to use a signal to create experience and education automaticaly when you create a profile.

Comment: okay but who would be the sender of that post_signal? I am lost on these post_signals.

Comment: the `Profile` model.

Comment: def create_exp(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        experience = Work_Experience.objects.create(profile=instance)
        education = Education.objects.create(profile=instance)

post_save.connect(create_exp, sender=Profile)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I used the signal mentioned above but still getting the same error.

Comment: Once I solve this bug, I will proceed to make a formset, so user can add multiple job experiences, like we add experiences in linkedin. Is my approach correct?

Comment: Please avoid making more than one question in a same post.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that,i recommend you read django docs. just Do this:
**Update here**

The code bellow work as expected..

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from latiro_app.managers import UserManager



class User(AbstractBaseUser):
     email         = models.CharField(verbose_name='email or phone number ', max_length=50, unique=True )
     first_name    = models.CharField('first name', max_length=15,blank=True)
     last_name     = models.CharField('last name', max_length=15,blank=True)
     country       = CountryField(blank=True)
     date_joined   = models.DateTimeField('date joined', auto_now_add=True)
     slug          = models.SlugField('slug', max_length=50, unique=True, null=True) 
     is_active     = models.BooleanField('active',default=False)
     is_staff      = models.BooleanField('staff', default=False)
     email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)


     objects = UserManager()

     USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
     REQUIRED_FIELDS = []


     class Meta:
         db_table = "users" 
         permissions = (
            ("edit_user", "Edit User"),
            )








class WorkExperience(models.Model):
     job_title       = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
     company         = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
     description     = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
     exp_start_date  = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
     exp_end_date    = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
         db_table = "experience"

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.job_title)


class Education(models.Model):
    degree      = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    school      = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    edu_start_date  = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    edu_end_date    = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "education"

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.degree)




class Profile (models.Model):
    user            = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete= models.CASCADE,
                                     verbose_name='list of users', null=True)
    experience    = models.ForeignKey(WorkExperience, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    education     = models.ForeignKey(Education, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)




    def __str__(self):
        return (self.user)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "profile"

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and not kwargs.get('raw', False):
        profile = Profile(user=instance)
        profile.save()
```

This should work. Tested on my database:

```
+----+--------------+---------------+---------+
| id | education_id | experience_id | user_id |
+----+--------------+---------------+---------+
|  1 |         NULL |          NULL |       2 |
+----+--------------+---------------+---------+
```

The null values on education_id and experience_id will be update by user_id instance when updating profile.

Now User can update his/her profile like this:
**note**:i'm not using signal.

```
#Form.py 
class EducationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    degree         = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=False)
    school         = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=False)
    edu_start_date = forms.DateField(required=False, 
                     input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
    edu_end_date   = forms.DateField(required=False, 
    input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)


    class Meta:
        model= Education
        fields =["degree","school", "edu_start_date","edu_start_date"]

#View.py 
class EducationFormView(UpdateView):
    model = Education
    form_class = EducationForm
    template_name = 'latiro_app/education_form.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('users:profile_settings',
                                            args =(self.object.id,))

    def get(self, form, ** kwargs):
       profile_instance = get_object_or_404(self.model, user_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        #Pass user profile data to the form 
        context = {'form':self.form_class(instance=profile_instance)}
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            kwargs['ajax_form'] = render_to_string(self.template_name, context, request=self.request )
            return JsonResponse(kwargs)
        else:
            return render(self.request, self.template_name, context)
```

Comment: Your post_save signal is not working, still the same error.
**'NoneType' object has no attribute 'job_title'**

Comment: Could post the whole trace?

Comment: @Ahsaan-566 The signal for the OP should be working but he called the form `save` method with `commit=False` that prevents the instance to be saved and in consequence, the signal is not triggered.

Comment: Silas still didn't work, might have to do something with what Raydel said.
@RaydelMiranda I changed it to commit=True, it still didn't work.

Comment: I edited my answer, i have just tested  it on my database